# Bash array size saying it's twice as large as I expect it to be

Tags: arrays, bash

I have the following code:

```
commit_hashes_raw=(`git cherry origin/Server_Dev`)
echo ${#commit_hashes_raw[@]}
echo ${commit_hashes_raw[@]}
```

that is producing the following output:

```
2
+ 6f0de9d07538db5d6428acd083c4a4527751596b
```

The first line is supposed to be the size of the array and the second is the contents. The obvious problem here is the discrepancy between the two values though. I've run this on another data set and a 50 element array was being reporting by the middle line as 100 elements long.

Am I using the wrong method for finding the size or is there something funky with my array?

Comment: Are there not 2 elements in this array? It looks like there are to me: the `+` and then the 40 character hex string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array has two elements - the `+` and then the hash.  When setting an array from command output, the elements are whitespace-separated, not newline-separated.

You could do this:

```
commit_hashes_raw=($(git cherry origin/Server_Dev | awk '{print $NF}'))
```

Or, somewhat less efficiently without calling out of the shell:

```
commit_hashes_raw=()
while read plus hash; do 
  commit_hashes_raw+=("$hash")
done < <(git cherry origin/Server_Dev)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the `+` symbols are adding extra elements to your array. You could try and filter them out when creating the array. Something like:

```
commit_hashes_raw=(`git cherry origin/Server_Dev | cut -d' ' -f2`)
```